# Mac Mini needs HDMI unplug-replug after it's been asleep

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, hdmi, television

I have a Mac Mini hooked up to my TV in my living room, connected via my audio received, and via HDMI.

If I leave the Mac until it goes to sleep, the TV screen goes blue (as expected), and the Mini goes to sleep.

If I then try to wake the Mini using the keyboard or the button on the back, the Mini wakes up fine, but the TV remains on the blue screen, and I have to unplug and re-plug the HDMI cable for the TV to decide what it's doing and show the display.

I'm using latest Mavericks, and no adapters, just straight from the mini to the AV receiver (same way my other devices are connected). I've tried plugging the HDMI directly from TV-Mini without the AV Receiver, just to ensure the receiver isn't the issue. It isn't :)

Any idea what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: How old is your TV? It sounds like it might be an HDCP issue.
What applications do you have open on your Mac? Any media applications like Quicktime/iTunes/etc. ?

Comment: The TV is a couple of years old, it's an LG LED. The Mac runs Plex Media Center mainly.